# show hidden field when "Other" option in select tag is selected

Tags: jquery, select

input field with id = field0 is a hidden field but still gets value from select, but when user select "Other", input text field0 will appear.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#selectNo').val($('#selectNO option:selected').val());

  $('#selectNo').bind('change', function() {
    $('#field0').val($('#selectNo option:selected').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectNo">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<input id="field0" value="" style="display:none;"/>
```

Comment: 1. The input is not hidden. 2. What exactly is your expected result ?

Comment: Try `input#field0{ display:none; }` in CSS and make `display:block` when `other` is selected.

Comment: I mean, input text should be hidden but still gets value from select tag... it will only show when Other option is selected. Sorry, I forgot to add style="display: none;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initially hide your textbox by using css's `display: none` property on the id `#field0`. Then, within your jQuery, you can use a `if` statment to check whether the option with the value `other` has been selected, and if it has you can display the textbox using the `.show()` method, otherwise, if the `other` option is not selected you can hide it using the `.hide()` method.

See example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $otherField = $("#field0");
  $('#selectNo').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value === 'other') {
      $otherField.val("");
      $otherField.show();
    } else {
      $otherField.hide();
      $otherField.val(this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#field0 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectNo">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<input id="field0" value="" />
```

Comment: i guess the OP wants to add value to the input even if the 'other' value is not selected.

Comment: @MihaiT oh yeah, you're right. I've updated my answers, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I want to empty the input field value if Other is selected... I can't use value === "", since the "Please select" has value=""...

Comment: @porsche I've edited my answer, is this what you're after?

Comment: @NickParsons unfortunately, the value of other options isn't captured by field0 :( The input text acts as the container of any of value selected. it's just that the case for Other option is different

Comment: @porsche what do you mean by "the value of the other opttions _isn't captured_"?

Comment: @NickParsons I resolved my issue :D Thanks again so much

Answer (score 0):

You can add `show()` & `hide()` when selected text "Other".

```js
$(function() {
  $('#selectNo').val($('#selectNO option:selected').val());
  $('#field0').hide();
  $('#selectNo').bind('change', function() {
    $('#field0').val($('#selectNo option:selected').text());
    if ($('#selectNo option:selected').text() == "Other")
      $('#field0').show();
    else $('#field0').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectNo">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<input id="field0" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a bit of refactoring to your code.

It's very easy to check what value/text has the selected option and hide/show the input according to that

```js
const input = $('#field0');
$("#selectNo").on('change', function() {
  const selectedOptionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

  input.val(selectedOptionText);
  selectedOptionText === 'Other' ? input.show() : input.hide();
})
```

```css
#field0 {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectNo">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<input id="field0" value="" />
```